# How to implement jQuery .on() function using plain Javascript and document query selectors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, mouseevent

[jquery on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) allow the DOM event to trigger on an element that may be inserted in the future. How can this be implemented using plain Javascript especially a `mouseenter` event on elements with a certain class without jQuery and using modern [document.querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

Comment: I think that jQuery source code will help you. Watch there, jQuery written on pure javascript

Comment: Check the [DOMEvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events), more specifically `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Comment: not hard to find in a web search *"javascript event delegation"*

Comment: @charlietfl It is easy to do when you just want a click event. But how do you implement mouseenter?

Comment: @Nevershowmyface Looking specifically for mouse enter event inside the DOM subtree

Comment: @MysterX Correct I looked but the logic is not as straight forward and easy to understand. Posting this question for others to benefit from it by having a easy to understand solution specifically for this.

Comment: You'd have to 'delegate' mouseover instead: `document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest && e.target.closest('.myClass') === e.target) {
    console.log('some stuff here');
  }
}, false);` (not really tested and supposing you don't need to handle older browsers regarding DOM node closest() method!)

Comment: what difference does it make if it's click or mouseenter? Concepts are the same

Comment: @charlietfl event propagation is quite specific for mouseenter event. If you bind it to document, it would never be firedfor any element inside DOM. Jquery btw use a special event for delegating it

Comment: @A.Wolff good point, wasn't thinking about that

Comment: @MysterX cool. any tips about which file of those hundreds that jQuery source consists of contains the implementation of it?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter

For anyone interested in implementing code is below:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li>
    <ul class="enter-sensitive">
      <li>item 1-1</li>
      <li>item 1-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="enter-sensitive">
      <li>item 2-1</li>
      <li>item 2-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  var delegationSelector = ".enter-sensitive";

  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
    var target = event.target,
        related = event.relatedTarget,
        match;

    // search for a parent node matching the delegation selector
    while ( target && target != document && !( match = matches( target, delegationSelector ) ) ) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    // exit if no matching node has been found
    if ( !match ) { return; }

    // loop through the parent of the related target to make sure that it's not a child of the target
    while ( related && related != target && related != document ) {
        related = related.parentNode;
    }

    // exit if this is the case
    if ( related == target ) { return; }

    // the "delegated mouseenter" handler can now be executed
    // change the color of the text
    target.style.color = "orange";
    // reset the color after a small amount of time
    setTimeout(function() {
        target.style.color = "";
    }, 500);


  }, false);


  // function used to check if a DOM element matches a given selector
  // the following code can be replaced by this IE8 compatible function: https://gist.github.com/2851541
  function matches( elem, selector ){
    // the matchesSelector is prefixed in most (if not all) browsers
    return elem.matchesSelector( selector );
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Ya IE doesn't support `closest()` at all, so you have to use polyfill for `matches()` and iterate through parent nodes.