# hover over the box, it should change its position randomly remove jquery without affecting code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouseover

I have done this far but the code isn't working. It's working in fiddle but here it isn't. I am attaching a solution which I want and the code as far as I have done. I have somehow figured out that with jQuery it's working but I don't want to use jQuery or tell me how to use jQuery in sublime text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Catch Me</title>
<style>
button {
    background-color: rgb(228, 6, 248);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <button name="button">Catch Me</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("button").on({
        mouseover:function(){
            $(this).css({
                left:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
                top:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The solution I want is this:
https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/0000000000001878.gif

Comment: Any errors in dev console?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to use Javascript and not jQuery?  Right now, you have an error because you are trying to use jQuery without the library included.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561655/how-to-implement-jquery-on-function-using-plain-javascript-and-document-query)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Catch Me</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
button {
    background-color: rgb(228, 6, 248);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <button name="button">Catch Me</button>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("left", "" + (Math.random()*200) + "px");
            $(this).css("top", "" + (Math.random()*200) + "px");
        });
    });
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check solution?